# Google Cloud Messaging e Padronização de Sincronizações

Tags: android, web-service, api, design-pattern, google-cloud-messaging

Estou construindo um projeto em que será utilizado o GCM do Google, algo novo em meus projetos, e gostaria de saber o seguinte.

Na hora que o usuário realizar o seu cadastro quem irá requisitar os primeiros dados do servidor será o cliente, e depois que o usuário estiver cadastrado quem irá requisitar novas informações será o Google Cloud Messaging. Porém gostaria de saber se não seria interessante logo após o usuário cadastrar-se no sistema, o GCM era quem enviasse as informações e configurações iniciais do sistema para o cliente, deixando o código responsável pelas sincronizações tudo em um só lugar, neste caso, na lógica do GCM, porém não sei se com essa maneira demoraria para o usuário ter o primeiro acesso ao sistema.

Também tem outra opção, criar um arquivo Java em que são chamados a partir da regra de negócio tanto da chamada do servidor para cliente, quanto do cliente para servidor.

Se tiverem exemplos sobre padronização com APIs, principalmente do GCM, quanto a outras regras de negócio de um sistema também agradeço.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após o usuário ter preenchido o cadastro pode sim haver uma certa demora enquanto o aplicativo se registra junto ao GCM, passa ao seu servidor o *Registration id* e o seu servidor manda a primeira *push notification*. Eu diria que é uma demora mais ou menos da mesma ordem da que leva o *WhatsApp* para receber o SMS de confirmação do número do usuário no momento do primeiro uso (desconsiderando que as tecnologias de comunicação envolvidas são diferentes). Pode valer a pena para você que o aplicativo espere por essa primeira *push notification* ou não.

Como você falou, a alternativa seria centralizar a regra de negócio que solicita os dados na forma de um *Web Service*, e fazer o aplicativo solicitar esses dados em duas situações: após o usuário efetuar o cadastro e sempre que o aplicativo receber uma *push notification* (que seria simplesmente um *ping* avisando que há algo novo no servidor, sem especificar o quê). Nos dois casos o procedimento seria o mesmo: chamar o *Web Service* de sincronização.